# How to change several nested numpy arrays into one multidimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy `a = np.load('test.npy')` file with these nested numpy array:

```
In [21]: a.shape
Out[21]: (6886, 3)

In [22]: a[0].shape
Out[22]: (3,)

In [23]: a[0][0].shape
Out[23]: (787, 6)
```

Is there a simple way to change `a` to be a 4 dimensional array with shape: `(6886, 3, 787, 6)`?

Comment: Looks like `a.dtype` is `object`.  Are you sure all elements have the same shape (787,6)?  If not the task is impossible.  If they do, you can use `np.stack` (but have to first reshape the outer array).

Comment: You are correct. The problem is that not all arrays have the same (786,6) shape. How to add `np.nan` values for arrays that are short: e.g. (506,6) so that they all become same shape: (787,6)?

Answer (score 1):

I would hate to do it this way, but all that comes to mind is making a second array of the desired shape and slice your data into it.  I have to admit that I am having difficulty understanding the shapes of each sub-array...it seems counter intuitive.  Anyway, this solution will be slow, but you can do it once and save the array and never do it again.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.load('test.npy')
b = np.full((6886, 3, 787, 6), np.nan)

for row in range(6886):
    for col in range(3):
        tmp = a[row][col]
        b[row, col, :tmp.shape[0], :tmp.shape[1]] = tmp
```

Does this make sense/work?

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to do, but I was hoping to find a way to avoid python for loops. Thanks!